# access variable containg spaces in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create/access a directory contain spaces. I know that 
I can create in this way mkdir -p ' asd qwe'.

But I need to put that value to a variable and access it. Following will script create 2 directory as expected.

```
   FOL="asd qwe"    
   mkdir -p "$FOL"
```

But how can I assign that value to a single variable and do it?

Comment: `Following will script create 2 directory as expected` -- No the command creates a single directory named `asd qwe`

Comment: It works fine to me.

Comment: Sorry guys. It working for me also. I don't know why it was working for me initially. If I get to know why it was not working earlier I will update here.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you wrote it:

```
FOL="asd qwe"    
mkdir -p "$FOL"
```

will make a *single* directory called `asd qwe`

Comment: Sorry guys. It working for me also. I don't know why it was working for me initially. If I get to know why it was not working earlier I will update here

Answer (score 0):

your script is doing what you need

```
root@asd:~# FOL="asd qwe"
root@asd:~# mkdir -p "$FOL"
root@asd:~# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 25 13:29 asd qwe
```